# Crontab with wget running one command but not another

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron

I have the following crontab file where the first wget command works but the other doesn't. The code on the two urls is identical, just one is on my development domain and the other is the production domain.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/news/bin
MAILTO=me@mydomain.com
#
# check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly, and cron.monthly
#
-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons /dev/null 2>&1

* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://dev.mydomain.com/cron/cron.php #Works fine

* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://live.mydomain.com/cron/cron.php #Does not work
```

I have tried commenting out the working command, in case it didn't like running 2 together, but this made no difference.

I have checked that the "live" URL works when run in the browser.

I get no errors either from crontab or in the apache logs.

Just nothing happens.

I have restarted the cron daemon and even rebooted the server.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

**EDIT**
OK I added in code to log errors and now it works:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/news/bin
MAILTO=me@mydomain.com
#
# check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly, and cron.monthly
#
-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons /dev/null 2>&1

* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://dev.mydomain.com/cron/cron.php >> /srv/www/dev/cron/CRONdev_LOG.txt 2> /dev/null 

* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://live.mydomain.com/cron/cron.php  >> /srv/www/live/cron/CRONlive_LOG.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Whilst I am please it works now, I would still like someone to explain why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally figured this out and it was really easy, but I will keep the question here for any other people like me who may have struggled.

There was originally no line break at the end of the crontab file, so the last command didn't run. When I edited it and added the error checking I added the linebreak on without realising, thus making it work.

After a little Googling I found this mentioned in a few places, but it doesn't seem to be too common knowledge.

Also, as it threw no error it made it very difficult to spot.